# Silverlight grid has gridlineslines on one side but not the other

Tags: silverlight

In the following Silverlight app, the grid on the right side has gridlines, and the grid on the left does not. I cannot see  why this is. The preference would be NO underlines at all. the code is here: http://pastebin.com/JcVS7Xxq

and pic of the app: you can see the grid gridlines on the right side.

http://img827.imageshack.us/img827/3379/sa001p.png

Comment: have you found the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pastebin.com link does not work for me to see the code - and generally it is preferred if you strip out as much code as possible and post it in the question.  That way, when future folks stumble upon this via Google searches or whatever, it is relatively contained Q & A all in one page.

Also, in your image, I don't see underlines anywhere, so I'm confused on what the question really is.  Can you maybe draw an arrow or a big red circle or something on the image to point out which part is not doing what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem:

Your first datagrid is declared like so:

```
<data:DataGrid x:Name="dgLeft" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  VerticalAlignment="Center">
```

and your second one:

```
<data:DataGrid x:Name="dgRight" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"  Background="White" Width="Auto" GridLinesVisibility="All" AlternatingRowBackground="WhiteSmoke" RowBackground="White" >
```

I'd make them have the same properties but at least get rid of the `GridLinesVisibility="All"` from the second datagrid.